# Reverse CSS3 transition

Tags: css, animation, transition, reverse

http://micheresources.com/html/j-crew-slider/

I'm wondering how to reverse an animation? As you hover over each navigation item to the left, you'll notice how the black bar just pinches to the top left corner rather than slides left when you hover over the next item. How can I make it slide out similar to how it slid in?

The black bar is an `<a>` tag that's appended to each navigation item when the `activeSlide` class is applied on hover, then removed at the next hover.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function activateItem(index) {
        $('#slideshow-nav').children('li').each(function (i) {
            var $item = $(this);
            if (i == index) {
                if ($item.children('a').length == 0) {
                    $item.append('<a href="#">' + titles[i] + '</a>');
                }
            } else {
                $item.children('a').hide(400, function() {
                    $item.children('a').remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }

    var titles = ["New Styles", "June PVE", "Double Hostess Rewards"];
    $("#slideshow").before("<ul id='slideshow-nav'></ul>")
    .cycle({
        fx:         "scrollVert",
        rev:            "scrollVert",
        speed:          600,
        timeout:        0,
        pagerEvent:     "mouseover",
        pager:          "#slideshow-nav",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            return "<li><span>" + titles[index] + "</span></li>";
        },
        onPagerEvent: function (index) {
            activateItem(index);
        }
    });
    activateItem(0);
});
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow-nav li a {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 285px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -285px;
    -webkit-transition: left 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: left 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: left 500ms ease;
    transition: left 500ms ease;
}
    #slideshow-nav li.activeSlide a { left: 0; }
```

Comment: Post the code that sets `activeSlide`.

Comment: `activeSlide` is part of the jQuery Cycle plugin. It's applied to the corresponding navigation item of the current slide.

Comment: Well I dunno what to tell you then. Try going without that plugin, it is likely quietly modifying the DOM in ways that break CSS transitions. This is exactly why outdated jQuery plugins are really really bad. You should be able to just use similar CSS logic on your scrolling photo viewer as with the black sliders on your menu.

Comment: It's not outdated, it's actively maintained on GitHub and was last updated 2 months ago. The animation can be reversed, probably with jQuery, but not sure how to do it. I updated the OP with my current code that animates `.remove()` on the `<a>` tag when hovering on the next navigation item, but it needs to slide left instead of pinch.

Comment: well I'm glad you got it to work. I looked in Chrome and the animations do indeed use the CSS transitions (rather than jQuery/JS setting the DOM in a loop) so that looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the important bit in the code below, I think you just needed to add timing to the `.remove()`

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/wQLeb/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function activateItem(index) {
        $('#slideshow-nav').children('li').each(function (i) {
            var $item = $(this);
            if (i == index) {
                if ($item.children('a').length === 0) {
                    $item.append('<a href="#">' + titles[i] + '</a>');
                }
            } else {
                    $item.children('a').remove('slow'); // <-----Important bit
            }
        });
    }

    var titles = ["New Styles", "June PVE", "Double Hostess Rewards"];
    $("#slideshow").before("<ul id='slideshow-nav'></ul>")
    .cycle({
        fx:         "scrollVert",
        rev:            "scrollVert",
        speed:          600,
        timeout:        0,
        pagerEvent:     "mouseover",
        pager:          "#slideshow-nav",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            return "<li><span>" + titles[index] + "</span></li>";
        },
        onPagerEvent: function (index) {
            activateItem(index);
        }
    });
    activateItem(0);
});
```

Comment: @Eli It happens to the best of us.